# What wrong in creating Patches (msp)

Tags: .net, visual-studio, deployment, installation

I have problem with creating patches (MSP). I use the tutorial from link:http://www.codeproject.com/KB/install/dotnetpatching.aspx?fid=209224&df=90&mpp=25&noise=3&sort=Position&view=Quick&select=2567089

Assume that: I have an installer XYZ.msi.In this msi have file 'xyz.txt'

I build an patch from installer XYZ.msi and this patch name is patch1.msp. This patch will upgrade file 'xyz.txt'.

I build another patch from installer XYZ.msi and this patch name is patch2.msp. This patch will also upgrade file 'xyz.txt'.

If an user install my application from XYZ.msi and apply patch1.msp and continue apply patch2.msp -> I check content of xyz.txt, it is old because it is from patch1.msp. Please explain me.

If an user install my application from XYZ.msi and don't apply patch1.msp, only apply patch2.msp -> I check content of xyz.txt, it is the lastest because it is from patch2.msp.

Please help me explain the reason why. I have any wrong? Thanks.

Comment: What does the log of installing patch2 over patch1 say? Is component where xyz.txt file belongs re-installed when applying patch2 over patch1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In each patch you should increase the file version of the files you are patching. If they don't have a version (for example TXT files), you can try setting the Version column in [File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368596%28VS.85%29.aspx) table to a very high value.

This way the patch should always update the file.